# Automate repeated code for various types?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Is there is any way by which I can automate this

```
DeserializeComponent<IDComponent>(json, e);
DeserializeComponent<NameComponent>(json, e);
DeserializeComponent<PointLightComponent>(json, e);
// ...
```

As you can see here, the same code is executed for different types, but in C++ you can't store types in a `std::vector` as far as my knowledge goes. Is there is any way by which I can automate this? Like looping over the components that I add to a vector in application startup? Also, I want to avoid RTTI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types can't be stored in variables. Types are only for the compiler. Even RTTI doesn't store types in variables, but rather "names" of types.

I think you just want to make the code shorter by not having to type `DeserializeComponent<>(json, e);` over and over. Well, you **can** do that with *parameter pack expansion*.

```
template<typename... Components>
void DeserializeComponents(json_t& json, e_t& e)
{
    (DeserializeComponent<Components>(json, e), ...);
}

// ...

DeserializeComponents<IDComponent, NameComponent, PointLightComponent>(json, e);
```

The magic is in `typename... Components` - which says `Components` is not just one type argument but a list of type arguments - and `(DeserializeComponent<Components>(json, e), ...);` which says to copy-paste the function call for each `Components` argument, and join them together with the comma operator `,`

When the compiler expands the template, the expanded template looks like this:

```
void DeserializeComponents<IDComponent, NameComponent, PointLightComponent>(json_t& json, e_t& e)
{
    (
     DeserializeComponent<IDComponent>(json, e),
     DeserializeComponent<NameComponent>(json, e),
     DeserializeComponent<PointLightComponent>(json, e)
    );
}
```

Comment: Looks like I am gonna use this and put the parameter pack in a Macro, that way I can use that everywhere. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can store your types in `std::tuple<tag<Ts>...>` or `TypeList<Ts...>`
and then use variadic template.

```
template <typename T> struct Tag{ using type = T; };

using MyTypes = std::tuple<Tag<IDComponent>, Tag<NameComponent>/*, ...*/>;

// And then do something like
void foo()
{
    // ...
    apply([&](auto tag){ DeserializeComponent<typename decltype(tag)::type>(json, e) },
         MyTypes{});
}
```

Comment: Note that types can only be "stored" at compile time this way - `MyTypes` isn't a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* also do it by wrapping the function call to `DeserializeComponents<T>(...)` inside a functor which recursively calls itself with the different types provided to it through a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

```cpp
// Other stuff...

// The code below works only with compilers that support C++11 or above
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct deserialize {
    template <typename A, typename B>
    void operator()(A&& a, B&& b) const {
        DeserializeComponent<T>(std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b));
        deserialize<Ts...>{}(std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b));
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct deserialize<T> {
    template <typename A, typename B>
    void operator()(A&& a, B&& b) const {
        DeserializeComponent<T>(std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b));
    }
};

// Other stuff...
```

Then you'd be able to do this:

```cpp
deserialize<IDComponent, NameComponent, PointLightComponent/*, ...*/>{}(json, e);
```